# Is it possible to spoof HttpRequest.UserHostAddress (REMOTE_ADDR)?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

As an *additional* measure for securing a web application, I'm considering implementing client IP whitelisting.

The preferred way seems to be: do this at the router. However, this is a significant administrative burden in my scenario.

I would like to do this in software, on the web server. Is there a reason why this is less secure?

Answer (score 2):

The HttpRequest.UserHostAddress is retrieved from the source ip number in the http request that is sent from the end user to your server. An http request is divided in several ip packets, and the source ip number is a field in each ip packet. Anyone on the net may craft ip packets with any ip number in the source field and send them to you.

However, the usefullness of this is somewhat restricted. When you respond to an http request, the response is sent to the source ip number in the request. The attacker will not recieve the response unless he is able to intercept the response on its way to the reciever. As an example: If the attacker send you a login request with a username and password, then you probably respond with a cookie. But since the cookie is sent to the fake source ip, the attacker will never see it.

IP spoofing is not technically difficult, but since the attacker will not recieve the response, it is mostly used for attacks that can be done with a single request.

Routers and firewalls may also protect you against malicious ip packets with false source ip's. Most firewalls will i.e. block packets from the external net with a source ip from the internal net.

Answer (score 1):

Client IP whitelisting at the router level is done to keep traffic out of a network because you don't want hosts communicating with your servers if they aren't from the right neighborhood.  This protects the servers from any number of OS-level attacks that only require access to the network stack.

What you are effectively talking about is using IP whitelisting as another factor for authentication on your server.  It will not help you against a hacker that has the right attacks because unauthorized clients are still able to reach your server at the network stack level.

Both methods are susceptible to IP spoofing, and guarding against that is the responsibility of your network team.  On a properly secured network you don't need to worry too much about malicious spoofing.

So, from a security standpoint it doesn't really hurt to use client IP whitelisting, but in the end, you're probably wasting your time maintaining the ACL.  If you want to control which hosts can connect to your application to limit your security profile, a firewall or at least a router access list is the way to go.

Edit: An OS-level firewall is also a choice you should consider if routing & switching changes are too cumbersome for your situation.

---

In response to comment:  A firewall whitelist would be more secure because it would be able to protect from OS-level attacks.

If you are not concerned with OS-level attacks then that part is not significant, and the end answer is yes, spoofing attacks are possible, and no, there is nothing you can do about it from within IIS or ASP.NET.

So I would still conclude that it is probably a waste of your time and the time of users who need to wait to be added to the whitelist.  But from a security standpoint it probably won't hurt you and might keep some attackers from profiling your server as a soft target.

Comment: I'm not really interested in OS-level attacks in this context - as you say they're the responsibility of the network team. The main scenario is to prevent casual unauthorized login attempts. (Why) is a firewall whitelist is more secure in this case? Thanks!