# How to get Client IP from network layer (Layer3) on Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, http, websocket, request.servervariables

When end-user opens up my webpage, how do i get the Client IP from Network layer? my integration partner is not accepting the IP taken from Server Variables as they feel REMOTE_ADDR from HTTP Request can be easily Spoofed. they want to take IP from Network layer when someone opens up the page and authorize. Possible using WebSocket? Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190083/is-it-possible-to-spoof-httprequest-userhostaddress-remote-addr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190083/is-it-possible-to-spoof-httprequest-userhostaddress-remote-addr) and similar pages you'll find if you search for `spoof remote_addr asp.net`. Basically, it's not easy, and if you're going to do it, you're most likely to be doing it at a a level that will affect the "network layer" just as much.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have shared links from stackoverflow. this guys is at networks & security and not accepting it. His policy is only to identify the source from Network layer. i can block all other IPs but only his network on Firewall. But the device is shared cannot be used only for his network.